# Toolbar menu item programmatic click

Tags: android, toolbar, android-optionsmenu, action-menu

I have this code

```
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        openSearch();
        return true;
    }
});
```

into `onCreate( )` of my `Activity`.

`OpenSearch` function call opens up google now like search view. This only happens when the user clicks on the search action item in the toolbar. In my case I want the search view to open up automatically when the activity starts. How can this menu item click be done programmatically.

I can't call openSearch directly because it needs the menu to be created.

Is there there any callbacks informing that action menus have been created ?

Comment: can't you use yourview.performclick()?

Comment: how do I know when its ready ?

Comment: Override `Activity#onPrepareOptionsMenu()` - it's called when menu is initialized

Comment: I am not sure about onPrepareOptionsMenu(), but you can add `GlobalLayoutListener` for your tollbar layout and override `onGlobalLayout()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
 tollbarLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
        new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                     tollbarLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                     tollbar.performclick();
                }

            }
        });
```